# make error installing Qsynth

Tags: macos, makefile, target, rule

Mac OSX 10.7.5

I am just trying to install Qsynth a GUI controller for fluidsynth. When I run make -d I get the following message -

```
...
Considering target file `src/qsynthAboutForm.ui'.
     File `src/qsynthAboutForm.ui' does not exist.
...
No implicit rule found for `src/qsynthAboutForm.ui'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `src/qsynthAboutForm.ui'.
    Must remake target `src/qsynthAboutForm.ui'.
make: *** No rule to make target `src/qsynthAboutForm.ui', needed by `src/qsynth'.  Stop.
```

The file does exist in src/ and the Makefile spelling etc. is OK.

Any ideas?
Thanks
Marc

I executed the command on just qsynthAboutForm.ui and then on the entire directory.
Thanks

```
unknown0023121f2421:src Marc$ pwd
/Applications/qsynth-0.3.8/src
unknown0023121f2421:src Marc$ ls -l qsynthAboutForm.ui
-rw-r--r--  1 Marc  staff  3928 Jul  8  2013 qsynthAboutForm.ui

unknown0023121f2421:src Marc$ ls -l
total 1200
-rw-r--r--   1 Marc  staff   3529 Dec  2 15:09 CMakeLists.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 Marc  staff   2835 Jan 26 15:11 Makefile
-rw-r--r--   1 Marc  staff   1812 Apr  9  2010 cmakeconfig.cmake
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   2813 Dec 31 05:24 config.h.in
-rw-r--r--   1 Marc  staff  26764 Jan 26 15:11 config.log
-rwxr-xr-x   1 Marc  staff  28428 Jan 26 15:11 config.status
drwxr-xr-x@ 27 Marc  staff    918 Dec 31 05:24 images
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff  11158 Jul  8  2013 qsynth.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff    431 Aug  4 11:30 qsynth.desktop.in
-rw-r--r--   1 Marc  staff   5017 Jan 18 15:56 qsynth.mak
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff    224 Mar 26  2010 qsynth.pro
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff    954 Mar 26  2010 qsynth.qrc
-rw-r--r--   1 Marc  staff   2773 Jan 26 15:11 qsynth.spec
-rw-r--r--   1 Marc  staff   2797 Dec 31 05:16 qsynth.spec.in
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   1442 Jan 13  2013 qsynthAbout.h
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   3178 Jul  8  2013 qsynthAboutForm.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   1535 Jul  8  2013 qsynthAboutForm.h
-rw-r--r--   1 Marc  staff   3928 Jul  8  2013 qsynthAboutForm.ui
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   1893 Jul  2  2007 qsynthChannels.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   1770 Jul  3  2007 qsynthChannels.h
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff  14078 Jul  8  2013 qsynthChannelsForm.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   2546 Jul  8  2013 qsynthChannelsForm.h
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   6133 Jul  8  2013 qsynthChannelsForm.ui
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   6001 Dec 28  2012 qsynthDialClassicStyle.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   1772 Dec 28  2012 qsynthDialClassicStyle.h
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   5484 Dec 28  2012 qsynthDialPeppinoStyle.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   1559 Dec 28  2012 qsynthDialPeppinoStyle.h
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff  16827 Dec 28  2012 qsynthDialSkulptureStyle.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   1458 Dec 28  2012 qsynthDialSkulptureStyle.h
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   6690 Dec 28  2012 qsynthDialVokiStyle.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   1517 Dec 28  2012 qsynthDialVokiStyle.h
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   2306 Jul  2  2007 qsynthEngine.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   2129 Jul  2  2007 qsynthEngine.h
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   4335 Jan 13  2013 qsynthKnob.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   2806 Jan 13  2013 qsynthKnob.h
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff  70686 Jul  8  2013 qsynthMainForm.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   4965 Jul  8  2013 qsynthMainForm.h
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff  33978 Jul  8  2013 qsynthMainForm.ui
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   5381 Mar 26  2010 qsynthMessagesForm.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   2289 Mar 26  2010 qsynthMessagesForm.h
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   2241 Mar 26  2010 qsynthMessagesForm.ui
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff  11227 Sep 12  2009 qsynthMeter.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   4024 Sep 12  2009 qsynthMeter.h
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff  31060 Dec 22  2012 qsynthOptions.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   3251 Dec 22  2012 qsynthOptions.h
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   9698 Jul  9  2010 qsynthOptionsForm.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   1878 Mar 26  2010 qsynthOptionsForm.h
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff  22877 Jul  9  2010 qsynthOptionsForm.ui
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff  11433 Dec 29  2012 qsynthPresetForm.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   2142 Jul  8  2013 qsynthPresetForm.h
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   5929 Jul  8  2013 qsynthPresetForm.ui
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   6848 Dec 22  2012 qsynthSetup.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   2730 Dec 22  2012 qsynthSetup.h
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff  31309 Jul  8  2013 qsynthSetupForm.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   2550 Jul  8  2013 qsynthSetupForm.h
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff  35449 Jul  8  2013 qsynthSetupForm.ui
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   3569 Jul  8  2013 qsynthSystemTray.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   2164 Jul  8  2013 qsynthSystemTray.h
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   2986 Jul  8  2013 qsynthTabBar.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   1909 Jul  8  2013 qsynthTabBar.h
drwxr-xr-x   5 Marc  staff    170 Jan 26 15:11 src
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff    104 Sep 25  2010 src.pri.in
-rw-r--r--@  1 Marc  staff   2164 Aug  4 11:30 src.pro
drwxr-xr-x@  8 Marc  staff    272 Dec 31 05:24 translations
drwxr-xr-x@  5 Marc  staff    170 Dec 31 05:24 win32
```

Comment: If make says it doesn't exist, then either it doesn't exist or you don't have permissions for it.  If you run `ls -l src/qsynthAboutForm.ui` what is the output?

Comment: ls -l src/qsynthAboutForm.ui

Comment: Sorry about that the output for src/qsynthAboutForm.ui is -rw-r--r-- 1 Marc staff 3928 Jul 8 2013 qsynthAboutForm.ui

Comment: That's not right.  `ls` should show the path in the output, if you did it right.  Please edit your question (rather than trying to add it in a comment where the formatting is all messed up), then use cut and paste to copy _both_ the command you typed _and_ the exact output into your question.  Also, be sure that your makefile is not recursing and changing directories to somewhere else while it runs.